# jquery cookie is not working is it a bug?

Tags: jquery, cookies

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" language="javascript">        </script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js" language="javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    alert("loaded");
    $.cookie('setdate', $.now());
alert( $.cookie('setdate') );
  });

</script>
```

jquery.cookie.js is downloaded from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie 
This simple code is not working. I m getting.. loaded then undefined. 
`Suggestions?`

Comment: Are you testing on file:// or on http:// ?

Comment: Both ways, this is not working. I tried on localhost and on http server too, both ways this gave same result

Comment: you can used  javascript cookies .

Comment: Mark a bug on github and get the developer to fix?

Comment: I tried your code in an HTML file and it worked.

Comment: Is jquery.cookie.js in the same dir as your html file?

Comment: [See it online](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/cookie.html).

Comment: @dinjas if it does not then OP would not even get first alert...

Comment: Yes, it is same directory, or else i wouldn't have had got undefined too.

Comment: Use this as src `https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js` and try..

Comment: @A.V From the readme : *"Do not include the script directly from GitHub"*. And I see no reason to try that anyway.

Comment: @dystroy: just to confirm its not the directory problem.. not for permanent use

Comment: @A.V There would be an error if the `$.cookie` function wasn't found, not the two alerts.

Comment: I tried https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js, still undefined.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dinjas/uVU3T/1/  The problem must be somewhere else, or something funky is going on with the jquery.cookie.js file

Comment: I tried on a new html using yours cookie.js still got the same result. How yours is working?

Comment: Did you turn cookies off in your browser ?

Comment: No, had it been the case, facebook would not been working I guess?

Comment: Ok, till now I tested it in Chrome, it wasn't working, I tried my code in Firefox and explorer for windows 7, and was working in both. Is it then bug of chrome?

Comment: I tried the code in Chrome without problem. You might have bad settings in your Chrome.

Comment: True, I reset all settings of Chrome and it worked. Thanks everyone helping here. Thanks dystroy, you rock!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, it can be tested [here](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/cookie.html).

The problem was a settings one in OP's browser. Resetting all settings fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works, it could just be a race condition and this would give it time to set it:

```
$(function() {
    alert("loaded");
    $.cookie('setdate', $.now());
     setTimeout(function() { alert( $.cookie('setdate') }, 2500 );
 });
```

Comment: After doing this, i didn't get the first alert too.